# How to open a Finder from anywhere?

Tags: keyboard, finder, mojave, shortcut

I am using macOS Mojave and would like to have a keyboard shortcut to open a new Finder window, similarly to how <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> opens the File Explorer in Windows.

I am aware that it is always open, but I'd like to get a key combination to open its window, or a new window, rather than clicking on the icon using mouse/trackpad.

Is there a handy way to do it?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "open Finder" The Finder is never 'closed', it runs constantly. You mean switch to it, or open a specific Finder window, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press and hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> kay and keep tapping the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key until you switch to Finder.app. Now after you have released the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, keep holding the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and then leave the <kbd>Command</kbd> key.

If no Finder window was previously open, it will open a new window. If one were open before, this will bring it to front. If one were open and minimized, this will maximize it and bring it to front.

Once Finder.app is in focus, you can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to open a new window.

Comment: I'm taking this as the answer since it is the simplest way. Thanks!

Comment: You can hardly call this a "shortcut". It involves a lot of manual labour. Opt-Cmd-Space is  a lot quicker, for the time being we have no real shortcut.

Answer (score 8):

By default <kbd>Opt-Cmd-Space</kbd> opens a new Finder window in search mode. Not exactly what you want, but navigating to any other part is then just a mouse click away.

Comment: This was actually what I wanted! I simply wanted the new window to open, from which I could get the left hand tree. The search is a plus imo.

Answer (score 3):

My personal recommendation is always use the `Spotlight Search` (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>) and then start typing any program that you need (`finder` in this case).

Comment: Well I don’t know what the OP tends to do in this Finder window but odds are that it is much faster to just type the name of whatever they’re looking for in the Spotlight search.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Mac Rumors forum:](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-finder.676966/)

> The way I do it is a quick two keyboard shortcut process. Press
>   Command Tab (similar to Window's Alt Tab function) and keep tabbing
>   until you select the Finder. Since Finder is always opened in Mac OS
>   it should always be available. After Finder is selected press Command
>   N to get a new Finder window.

Comment: Indeed, this works though it isn't exactly what I was expecting :)